# Why is this not a valid regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to retrieve a part of a string from a URL using `regex.exec()`it  but I am getting an error for some reason.  Hoping you guys can spot it.

I am trying to get this from the string -> `http://anotherdomain.com/image.jpg`

```
var haystack = 'http://domain.com/?src=http://anotherdomain.com/image.jpg&h=300';
var needle = /(?<=src=).+(?=&h)/;
var results = needle.exec(haystack);
```

So on load I am getting this error -> `SyntaxError: invalid quantifier`

So I tried adding single quotes around the needle but didn't work.  Adding quotes gives me `needle.exec` is not a function.

Comment: var URL=haystack.split("src=")[1].split("&")[0];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript regular expressions do not support lookbehind.

You might be able to get by with:

```
var haystack = 'http://domain.com/?src=http://anotherdomain.com/image.jpg&h=300';
var needle = /src=(.+)(?=&h)/;
var results = needle.exec(haystack);

// results is now ["src=http://anotherdomain.com/image.jpg", "http://anotherdomain.com/image.jpg"], so haystack[1] is what you want.
```

Comment: Do you know what is the equivalent to a look behind in JS?

Comment: Thanks! That worked...I had no idea I couldn't use lookbehind in JS..It seems to work in PHP...

Comment: @Rick: Yep, PHP supports lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use capturing parens instead of lookbehind:

```
results = haystack.match(/\?src=([^&]*)&/);

if (results) {
    result = results[1];
}
```